# hvplot points with geo true does not show the map

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, geo, hvplot

```
all_neighborhoods_df.hvplot.points('Lon', 'Lat', geo=True, color="gross_rent", 
                               size="sale_price_sqr_foot", frame_height=500, 
                               frame_width=700, title="Neighborhood Map")
```

When I looked through the documentation it said that having `geo=True` will bring the map but the result I received is this:

[image: this]

The result I should get is something like this:

[image: this]

Comment: Hmm, you'll need to provide more of your code.

Comment: I think it will help if you include a sample of your `all_neighborhoods_df` dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `tiles` parameter in `hvplot.points()`

The particular style shown in your example is `tiles='OSM'` (OSM: Open Street Maps)

Different tile options can be found in the [HoloViews documentation](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Tiles.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `geo` parameter just makes hvplot aware of your intention to display geographic data and as such it will handle projecting the data. You need to define `tiles` (e g. `'ESRI'`) to get a basemap (this is shown in the first example of the geographic user guide of the documentation).